# Prevent resource requests if null value

Tags: html, browser, background-image

Is there a way to prevent browsers from making GET requests when resources have a null value so that
`background-image:url(null)` doesn't make a request to `myCurrentUrl.com/null`

Comment: why not remove the rule (background-image) all together? or set it to `background-image: none`

Comment: I'm looking for more of a global fix for this rather than wrapping each element that has a img resource in a conditional. 

I've considered using a conditional in all my queries so that null is never returned or updating my database so every image field has a default value rather than null but I'm specifically looking for a way to allow a value but prevent the request. Maybe it's not worth it though.